# Simple String Recursion

Tags: c, string, loops, recursion, logic

I'm trying my hand out with strings, and I've run into a problem I can't debug.

The goal of this script is to run 5 tests on one string, detecting the string length of each string, while giving the string a parameter (Minimum characters to input, and max)
string in question is **str[]**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE 11
#define MIN_SIZE 5

void String_Insert_Recursion(char str[]);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   char str[SIZE];
   int i, str_lenght;

   printf("Enter a string of %i to %i characters:\n", MIN_SIZE, SIZE-1);
   for (i=0; i<5 ; i++)
   {
      String_Insert_Recursion(str);  
      str_lenght = strlen(str);
      printf("This string is %i long\n", str_lenght-1);
   }


   system("PAUSE"); 
   return 0;
}


 void String_Insert_Recursion(char str[])
{
   int i=0;
   while ((str[i] = getchar()) != '\n')
      i++;

   if (i>SIZE-1 || i<MIN_SIZE)
      {
      //SIZE-1 so that there's still ONE spot on the string for a null value.
      printf("Incorrect number of characters. Please Reenter\n");
      String_Insert_Recursion(str);
      }

   str[i+1]='\0';
   //This sets the null value at the end of the string
}
```

It works 100% fine, **if** you don't go over the Max or Min setup. The program will stop you and ask you to re-input your string if you do (As it should) but there's **something** that carries over.

- For example, if you write "**End**" as the string, it will ask you to
  re-put that since it's only 3 characters.
- If you write your next character as "**The End**" it will give you 3 characters (Which is
  incorrect, it should be 7 characters; Space included.)
- Writing "**The End**" again will give you the correct number of characters now.
- Tested to see if it's really reading the previous "**The End**" that you wrote, but it's not. So I have to assume the problem's going to be in some logic loop oversight on the recursion.

It feels like the program is mucking up at the **if statement** in the recursion (That's as far as I could narrow down the problem), I can't understand for the life in me why @__@ So far, I've tried clearing the string out using

```
str[0]='\0';
```

And planking that practically everywhere, to no avail however :(
Would really appreciate help! It's interesting to learn, but frustrating when you don't have any way to get a clue on what's really going wrong.

Thank you for reading!

---

**EDIT**: 
Moved `str[i+1]='\0';` under the `i++;` which will set a null value ahead of the string for every attempt. Turns out the problem was that it would set a null value to both working and unworking strings since it was placed in a bad spot. Thank you to **Dave** for this!

If you've got some interesting insight or another answer to add, I will definitely read it however! :)

Comment: Actually, when you do the check for string length in `String_Insert_Recursion` you might have already overwritten past the end of the array.

Comment: Your problem is in recursion rather than strings directly. Just use a loop. (specifically, `str[i+1]='\0';` is getting run for both the successful string *and* the unsuccessful string before it)

Comment: Didn't see that! Good catch :)

Stuck it under the i++, and it's working great so far, I'll put it under a stress test to see if I can screw it up or if it's fixed for good. 

Ahhhhh man, thanks Dave for that. I'll have to make sure I don't make a mistake like this in the future!

Answer (score 1):

You need to `return` after doing the recursion:

```
void String_Insert_Recursion(char str[])
{
    int i=0;
    while ((str[i] = getchar()) != '\n')
        i++;
    if (i < SIZE && i>=MIN_SIZE) {
        str[i+1]='\0';
    } else {
        printf("Incorrect number of characters. Please Reenter\n");
        String_Insert_Recursion(str);
    }   
}
```